# can I use expressions like 'calc' inside [style.width] directive?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use my variable inside calc() inside [style.width] directive in angular?

Something like this:

```
<div [style.width.px]="calc(100% - myWidth)">some texts </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

TS:

```
myWidth: string = '100px';
```

HTML:

```
<div [style.width]="'calc(100% - ' + myWidth + ')'">some texts </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also declare a style object in your .ts file:

```
mywidth = 20;
styleObj = {width: `calc( 100% - ${this.mywidth}px)`};
```

and put it into your html:

```
<div [ngStyle]="styleObj">some texts </div>
```